# In Pandas, how to send the output from groupby transform to the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                        'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})



group=df.groupby(['A','B'])

agg_df=group.agg({'D':lambda x: x[x>0].sum(), 'D':lambda x: x[x<0].sum()} )
```

Here I would like to get two additional variables in the **original dataframe df**.

One that is the sum of positive elements in D, and one that is the sum of negative elements in D. Using `agg` is straighforward, as you can see in the code above.

However, I would like to have these values **repeated** in the main dataframe for each line corresponding to a particular `groupby` combination.

The naive syntax would be to use:

```
transform_df=group.transform({'D':lambda x: x[x>0].sum(), 'D':lambda x: x[x<0].sum()} )
```

but thats fails.
What Am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if expressed in two lines, the logic becomes cleaner to write & read

```
df['d_pos_sum'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform(lambda x: x[x>0].sum())
df['d_neg_sum'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform(lambda x: x[x<0].sum())
```

Comment: thank you! but why I can write `agg_df=group.agg({'D': ['mean', 'max']} )` but not `agg_df=group.agg({'D': [lambda x: x.sum(), lambda x:x.max()]} )` ? In other words, am I forced to write two lines in this case?

Comment: you can pass in multiple functions, just not lambdas, define the functions in previous lines, i.e. `def d_sum(x): return x.sum()` & `def d_max(x): return x.max()`, then aggregate in one line: `agg_df = group.agg({'D': [d_sum, d_max]})`, but this solution is actually 3 lines.